# Can't install Apache Flex 4.13, prompted for credentials

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to install Apache Flex 4.13 SDK using the installer provided by Apache. In the middle of the install process I am prompted from credentials from the opensource.adobe.com server. I had installed the SDK before and this had not happened. Any clues on what might be causing this?

EDIT: Credentials are requested when trying to download afe.jar from http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/branches/4.y/lib

Comment: I had the same problem while installing Flex 4.11. Even though the installer did say it succesfully completed after clicking 'cancel' on the authentication prompt a couple of times, I encountered some very strange errors while trying to build a Flex project after. I resolved the issue by copy-pasting the correct SDK version's folder from a coworker's installation.

Comment: Will try installing on another machine and manually copying the files, then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This was an Adobe issue i.e.they password protected opensource.adobe.com. The Apache Flex installer configuration has since been updated to use another location.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into same problem.

Trying to install flex 4.9.1 using the installer pops up a prompt for credentials on opensource.adobe.com, when trying to download osmf.swc

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I know you don't yet have permission to comment, but this looks like a comment and you should use answers for answering a question.

Comment: Hey. Yes, i am new to stackoverflow, and did not really know i was doing wrong. I now have registered my account, and next time i will comment on answer. Edit: Oh! I now see, i must have 50 reputations to comment. So no comments from me (for now).

Comment: Looks like there is still an issue for some versions of the SDK. 4.12 and 4.12.1 are still broken, 4.9 and 4.10 should now work. For more details see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-34540.